# Material UI component with arrow

Tags: material-ui

Is there a Material UI component that is like a container/box with an arrow coming out of it like tooltips can do? I'll insert a screenshot of what I'm trying to do below. The only way I can think of right now is to just use tooltip and set open to always be true, but i was hoping there was an already built component for this that i just cant find

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure MUI doesn't have a component like that. Otherwise you should customize a [Paper](https://mui.com/components/paper/#main-content) component, [Popper](https://mui.com/components/popper) or [Box](https://mui.com/components/box/#main-content) or style a div.